# $A$ is dense in $A''$ in the strong topology (Murphy's book)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

In Lemma 4.1.4. Murphy is doing something strange that I don't seem to understand. for each $x\in H$ we find $v_n(x)$ such that it converges to $u(x)$. we wish to prove that is holds for EVERY $x$.

Murphy goes on to make this construction on $H^n$ so that in the end he can take $W$ (neighbourhood of $u$ in the strong topology) and show that there there is at least some $v_n(x)$ so it is indeed the sot closure.
What I don't understand is why he uses this $x_1,...x_n$ what is he trying to say?

surely not that $W$ is a sot neighbourhood of $u$ if $|(t-u)x_j|<\epsilon$ for finitely many $x_j$?!

Can someone illuminate this argument, please?

[image]

Comment: I feel obligated to point out that we're technically not supposed to paste images of the text we're asking questions about because the links can break, but I can see why you wouldn't want to in this instance. I guess the counterpoint one could make is that by paraphrasing / writing up as much of the text as possible yourself, via the "rubber duck method" you may inadvertently help yourself find an answer. As to your concrete question, it's been years since I studied functional analysis, and even then only at a shallow level, so I probably can't help (it appears to require some deeper thought).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I don't understand is why he uses this $x_1,...x_n$ what is he trying to say?
>
> surely not that $W$ is a sot neighbourhood of $u$ if $|(t-u)x_j|<\epsilon$ for finitely many $x_j$?!

Basic neighbourhoods are precisely those $W$. The argument in the first paragraph shows how to get $|(t-u)x|<\epsilon$, but for a single $x$. That's not enough for sot convergence, because if
$$
W=\{t:\ \|(t-u)x_j\|<\epsilon,\ j=1,\ldots,n\},
$$
after you apply the first paragraph to $x_1$ and get a $v$, you have no reason for $\|(v-u)x_2\|<\epsilon$, etc.

The trick with moving things to $H^n$ is that now points are of the form $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. So now you can apply the first paragraph to $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, while the algebra now consists of operators of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}v\\ &\ddots\\ && v\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So the first paragraph, applied to $\varphi(A)$ on $H^n$, produces $v$ such that
$$
\left\|\left(\begin{bmatrix}v\\ &\ddots\\ && v\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}u\\ &\ddots\\ && u\end{bmatrix} \right) \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\ \vdots\\ x_n\end{bmatrix}\right\|<\epsilon.
$$
This inequality is, by definition
$$
\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n\|(v-u)x_j\|^2\Big)^{1/2}<\epsilon. 
$$
In particular,
$$
\|(v-u)x_j\|<\epsilon,\qquad\qquad j=1,\ldots,n,
$$
which says precisely that $v\in W$.

Comment: Why are the basic neighbourhoods precisely those of $W$? shouldn't they be of the form $\|(v-x)x\|<\epsilon$ for every $x\in H$? Obviously not but why not, why do we take only finitely many $x_j's$ in the balls in the strict topology?

Comment: To be a family of neighbourhoods they need to have the property that the intersection of two of them contains another one; that obviously fails if you use a single $x$. As for why those neighbourhoods generate the sot topology, it depends on how you define the topology. If you define it in the usual way, as the locally convex topology generated by the seminorms $v\longmapsto\|vx\|$ for $x\in H$, it is standard that the $W$ as above give you a base for the topology.